# How do you create a Powershell boolean Calculated Property with a value that can be recognised by a WinForm Checkbox?

Tags: powershell, user-interface, checkbox

During retrieval of a larger data set, I am trying to create a calculated property called 'Checked' in Powershell, with an initial value of `$false`:

```
$var = [System.Collections.ArrayList](@($dataSource | Select-Object -Unique -Property @{Name='Checked';Expression={$false}},ID,Name))
```

This is then visualised in a WinForm DataGridView object, generated from Powershell:

```
$bAnalysesDataGrid                       = [System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView]::new()
$bAnalysesDataGrid.location              = [System.Drawing.Size]::new((20*$w),(210*$h))
$bAnalysesDataGrid.width                 = 1960*$w
$bAnalysesDataGrid.height                = 600*$h

[void]$bAnalysesDataGrid.Columns.Add([System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn]::new())
[void]$bAnalysesDataGrid.Columns.Add([System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn]::new())
[void]$bAnalysesDataGrid.Columns.Add([System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn]::new())
$bAnalysesDataGrid.Columns[0].Name             = "Checked"
$bAnalysesDataGrid.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "Checked"
$bAnalysesDataGrid.Columns[1].Name             = "ID"
$bAnalysesDataGrid.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "ID"
$bAnalysesDataGrid.Columns[2].Name             = "Name"
$bAnalysesDataGrid.Columns[2].DataPropertyName = "Name"

$bAnalysesDataGrid.DataSource = $var
```

However, when the 'Checked' property loads into the first column, the following error appears, which suggests the $false is being received as a String:

> The following exception occurred in the DataGridView:
> System.FormatException: Value 'False' cannot be converted to type 'Boolean'.

**How can I create a calculated property that works with the CheckBox, to start with a value of $false? I've tried various combinations of zeroes, strings and $ signs, none of which seems to behave correctly.**

Full error message:

[image: Exception]

Comment: Some code appears to be missing. Where do you bind `$var` to the DataGridView?

Comment: Thanks @MathiasR.Jessen - have added the missing line. Just using the 'DataSource' property for the DataGridView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data binding logic in Windows Forms doesn't quite know how to invoke PowerShell's extended properties correctly, so calculated properties, note properties or `[pscustomobject]` members won't work well with this approach.

Instead, use the `class` keyword to define a real .NET type, and member binding should then work:

```
class CheckableDataRow {
  [bool]$Checked
  [int]$ID
  [string]$Name
}

# fetch/construct data rows
$vars = $dataSource | Select-Object -Unique -Property @{Name='Checked';Expression={$false}},ID,Name 

# convert to CheckableDataRow's
$vars = $vars -as [CheckableDataRow[]]

# rest of the script remains the same...
```

Comment: Thanks! Will give this a try in the morning and accept if it works as expected. Have done a lot with PS but haven't really delved into defining Classes yet as the SDK's I tend to work with have fairly comprehensive object models.

Comment: when I attempt `$vars -as [CheckableDataRow[]]` it does not return any output - no discernible errors. Will keep trying to troubleshoot from this side. Prior to the attempted conversion `$vars` is a System.Array object with two members, all data as expected.

Comment: ah, got it working. The `ID` property as retrieved from the data source was typed as `String` and didn't seem to like the implicit conversion to `int`.

Comment: @SteveTaylor Great to hear you got it sorted out! FWIW The `-as` operator will always fail silently, replace the last statement with `$vars = $vars |ForEach-Object { [CheckableDataRow]$_ }` if you want each conversion to throw on failure :)

Comment: Good to know - the underlying object model for this case is consistent enough that it shouldn't happen again now that it's working, but now that I've done this once I'm more likely to do it again, so really appreciate having an extra tool for troubleshooting next time. Silent failures are the worst!